# Installing Civicrm on Drupal 7 site

Tags: drupal, installation

I have uploaded Civicrm 5.12.0 on a Drupal 7.65 site via FTP. After upload was completed, I attempted the installation script, but nothing happened. Is there a step that I forgot to do or wasn't aware of?

Comment: for people to answer a 'is there a step i forgot' you would need to spell out every step you took. In doing so, and comparing with the documentation, you may then work out what if anything you missed.

Comment: I installed the module via FTP upload. Then I attempted the installation script, as described in the documentation, but the installation screen isn't launching. My site is running on PHP version 7.2.7. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error log file of the webserver (probably apache2). If you see an entry like `PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 21426352 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0`
you will have to adapt the /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini file in order to rise the value of two parameters to v.gr. 32M:

```
upload_max_filesize = 32M
post_max_size = 32M
```

Don't forget to restart apache after updating php.ini at the command line interface by issuing:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Just for future reference, you should probably ask for more information before you answer a question as your answer may have nothing to do with the actual problem that the user is facing :)

Comment: @Ember Thank you for your suggestion, but I had the same problem last week: "nothing happens" and I solved it the way I described above. If you see my text, it includes the conditional sentence "If you see an entry like..." which protects me from the fact the problem would have nothing to do with the limits in the `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 0):

Installing CiviCRM on Drupal 7 guide is on the following link https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/install/drupal7/ . From your question is quite difficult to tell what you have done or what the issue can be (did you check Drupal db settings, system requirements etc)? What are the error messages if any? Did you test locally before attempting in production?